# How to clear saved password or formdata from iOS app

Tags: ios, ios4, uiwebview, browser-cache

App uses UIWebView, and what are the caching areas to lookout and clear when user logs out.

Cache.db
ApplicationCache.db (if applicable)
HTML5 databases
Cookies

1 . Anything else to look for?
2 . How to clear saved password or formdata ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once try with clearing NSHTTPCookies.....Use this code.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies
{
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, are you sure that this will delete pws and form data?

Comment: Yes.But please check once that it is working or not in your case.